# How to import/use an exported bean from an osgi bundle into another osgi bundle

Tags: maven, osgi

I am new to osgi and have very little experience with it. I have an osgi bundle which exports a bean as osgi service using  in the config xml file. I want to use that service in another osgi bundle. Can anybody tell me how to do that? I am using maven and felix osgi.

Comment: Sorry, what config.xml file is that?

Comment: @Miquel That config file exists in bundles' META-INF/spring/ folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter how the OSGi service is exported, using blueprint or smth else  - since it is an OSGi service, your bundle can get it from the OSGi service registry. 
For this you must:

1. Import its package in your bundle manifest, in order to declare the dependency. 
   You have to add
   Import-Package: com.acme.theservicepackage
   in META-INF/Manifest.mf
2. in your Activator class, you have to get the service from the service registry using your bundle context:

   timeRef = bc.getServiceReference(TimeService.class.getName());
       if (timeRef != null) {
       timeService = (TimeService) bc.getService(timeRef);
     }

Then you simply use the timeService  (or whatever interface your service is using) by calling its methods, whatever they are.

There are many details here, you can use the helper ServiceTracker class instead, or blueprint, or declarative services... But since you seem to be new to OSGi, I have left it as simple as possible and have shown the most basic way to do it.

There are demos [here](http://dz.prosyst.com/pdoc/mBS_SDK/um/runtime/osgi/docs/framework/index.html) for the basic OSGi services.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yesterday I left off exactly the same place as you mentioned in your answer. I am feeling excited that I am on right path :) One more question. Now I have the service timeService in my activator class, but how I will use it in other component of that same bundle? (I mean the same bundle in which activator I have the timeService)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use the service with blueprint? Your description "config xml" sounds a bit like it might be blueprint. In this case you can use

I have a full example on my website:
http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/DIBZ

The example shows how to export and import a service using blueprint.

Comment: Hi, I am not using blueprint. The bundle I have is developed by another programmer and he used spring framework I guess, because in META-INF/spring/ folder that config file exists and the bean is exported by that config file.

Comment: It does not matter how the service is exposed. You can use the service with a ServiceTracker, Spring DM, blueprint or declarative services. Simply use the technology that fits best into your project.